# Level of indentation in xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

By default xmllint appears to indent by 2 spaces, Is there a way to change the level of indentation on Windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you need to set the environment variable `$XMLLINT_INDENT` to be whatever you need (e.g. if you want 4 spaces use four spaces "    ").  From the docs:

> $XMLLINT_INDENT environment variable controls the indentation (default
>   value is two spaces " ")

You then need to run it with the `--format` flag. e.g.:

```
xmllint --format my_file_name.xml
```

Comment: I saw that documentation also, but how do you edit that environment variable for XMLLINT_INDENT on a Windows machine?

Comment: You should be able to do it via [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) or via the my System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables menu.

Comment: $XMLLINT_INDENT does not even exist in my system variables. Its simply an application that I have in a folder that is included my path in the environment variables.

Comment: It doesn't exist by default - if you add it, then the program will pick it up.

Comment: `XMLLINT_INDENT="  " xmllint --html --format - < temp.htm ` prints no indentation for me.